# Unit tests should mock all external services?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

I'm creating unit tests for a disk device manager which format disks, manage disk partitions and create logical volumes and groups in Linux. This disk manager is a class in a bigger application. I will certainly have to create tests which test the integration of (1) the disk device manager class and (2) the OS commands and libraries used to perform disk operations.

1) Would these tests be classified as unit or integration tests? They seem unit tests because they only test a module of my application, but they also seem integration tests because they depend on external code.

2) Is it worth it to also mock OS commands and external libraries behavior to create isolated unit tests?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the OS environment?  The short (nearly useless) answer is 'it depends' -- but is there an established vernacular for the OS environment in which you're working?  If so, my recommendation is to adopt that environment's convention for naming the types of tests -- it will make the most sense and be least astonishing to the next person who has to look at the code.

Comment: The OS is Linux, I do not know if there is a unit test vernacular in it. Anyway, I'd expect the answer to be OS independent. Is this matter a gray area in software testing theory? Reading http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html , I start to believe so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integration tests verify how two (or more) **real** components are working together. Usually the components have some well defined API and tests are run through it in order to ensure the API implementation. The unit tests are verify the one unit (class) only. We are using mocks to simulate the "external" behaviour in the unit tests.

Therefore when you test your component against the real system (OS) this is integration tests.

It is worth to prepare the mock in order to verify the class behaviour independ from the real environment. For example you may want to launch these unit tests after your builds (Continuous Integration) and verify the regression. In this case you want to run pretty fast and not deal with the real OS.